# Download file from gridview rowcommand

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, download, response

I've written out the below code to handle a file download which should occur on Gridview.RowCommand. It works in other places where I've used it (linkbutton outside of a gridview or similar control).

This Gridview is inside of an UpdatePanel.

```
Protected Sub gvBikeInsurance_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvBikeInsurance.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim ibtnExportToPDF As ImageButton = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("ibtnExportToPDF"), ImageButton)
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).RegisterPostBackControl(ibtnExportToPDF)

        Dim btnDelete As LinkButton = TryCast(e.Row.Cells(e.Row.Cells.Count - 1).Controls(0), LinkButton)
        btnDelete.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this insurance item');"
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub gvBikeInsurance_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvBikeInsurance.RowCommand

    Select Case e.CommandName
        Case "PDFExport"
            exportPolicy(e.CommandArgument)
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub exportPolicy(ByVal BikeInsuranceID As Integer)
    Dim args As New List(Of MySqlParameter)
    args.Add(New MySqlParameter("xbikeinsuranceid", MySqlDbType.Int32))
    args(args.Count - 1).Value = BikeInsuranceID

    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = db.execDB("InsuranceFiles_Select", CommandType.StoredProcedure, args.ToArray(), GeneralFunctions.ReturnType.DataReader, False)

    Dim output() As Byte
    If dr.HasRows Then
        dr.Read()
        output = dr("filedata")
    End If
    dr.Close()

    Dim outputstr As String = Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(output)

    Response.Clear()
    Response.ClearHeaders()
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "Policy Schedule.pdf"))

    HtmlToPdf.ConvertHtml(outputstr, Response.OutputStream)

    Response.End()
End Sub
```

The system captures user information from a form and writes HTML with it. This HTML is used to create a PDF file which is then supposed to be downloaded automatically.

The problem is that the file doesn't seem to be downloading unless I run it through step by step through the debugger. Standard execution just displays the UpdateProgress content which disappears after a little while.

Is there anything wrong with the code here? Most specifically in the RowDataBound and RowCommand routines and in the generation of Response.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Just spotted this error in Chrome's console:

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

So as it turns out, while possibly not best practice (I defer to more seasoned developers to dispute this), my code does work.

At least it would have worked, had I been using a `ToolkitScriptManager` as opposed to a `ScriptManager` when registering the postback control on my RowDataBound sub:

```
Protected Sub gvBikeInsurance_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvBikeInsurance.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim ibtnExportToPDF As ImageButton = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("ibtnExportToPDF"), ImageButton)
        ToolkitScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).RegisterPostBackControl(ibtnExportToPDF)

        Dim btnDelete As LinkButton = TryCast(e.Row.Cells(e.Row.Cells.Count - 1).Controls(0), LinkButton)
        btnDelete.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this insurance item');"
    End If
End Sub
```

You'll decide which to use when you add it to your page/master page. Note that if you're using controls from AJAX Control Tookit .NET 3.5, you must use the `ToolkitScriptManager`

For reference, the difference between [ScriptManager and ToolkitScriptManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348589/difference-between-script-manager-and-toolkit-script-manager)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because your application is trying to use Response methods in an updatePanel.  This will fail for several reasons:
http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx

Most notable, in your example, it's due to the update panel.

Instead, you can have the update panel open a page which starts the download, like this:

```
Private Sub exportPolicy(ByVal BikeInsuranceID As Integer)

 'store what you need to create the file in session variables
 Session("fileName") = foundAttachment.FileName
 Session("documentType") = foundAttachment.DocumentType
 Session("byteArray") = byteArray



'this registers a Javascipt function with the page.  You need to create a page Called "Download.aspx"
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.UpdatePanel1, Me.GetType, "ShowPopup", "window.open('DownloadPage.aspx');", True)
End Sub
```

Now, in your DownloadPage.Aspx page:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (Not IsPostBack) Then
        Dim fileName As String = Session("fileName")
        Dim docType As String = Session("documentType")
        Dim byteArray() As Byte = Session("byteArray")


        If (byteArray.Length > 0) Then
            Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(byteArray)
            Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(ms)

            Response.Clear()
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & fileName)
            Response.ContentType = docType
            Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray)
            Response.End()
            Response.Flush()
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

In my example, I am using byteArrays to create the file but you can use what ever method you need.

Comment: hmmm I had a similar problem with a linkButton in the UpdatePanel as well, I just set up a ClientPostBack Trigger to deal with that, and that's what I thought I've done in the RowDataBound method... I've seen it work once or twice as is though, but it's not reliable

Comment: In any case, I've taken the GridView out of the UpdatePanel and it's still throwing the exception...

Comment: Did you try it the way I suggested?  To have a separate page do the Response methods?

Comment: Actually, it turns out there's a difference between ScriptManager and ToolkitScriptManager. Changing my code above to use ToolkitScriptManager fixed the issue