# onokayscript not working with ajax modal popup extender

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

onokay script is not working in my code. My aim is to call asp button click event on clicking okay button and if it is cancel button, no need call the button click event. On below I have given the code which I wrote. Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="submit_Click" ValidationGroup="submt"/>
                 <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" cancelcontrolid="btnCancel" okcontrolid="btnOkay" targetcontrolid="submit" popupcontrolid="Panel1" popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" drag="true" backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG" OnOkScript="onok();"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
              <asp:panel id="Panel1" style="display: none" runat="server">
              <span id="overlay"></span>
                <div class="HellowWorldPopup">
                    <div class="PopupHeader" id="PopupHeader">Warning</div>
                    <div class="PopupBody">
                        <p>Do you want to change the password!!!</p>
                    </div>
                <div class="Controls">
                    <input id="btnOkay" type="button" value="Okay"/>
                    <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
                </div>
        </div>
</asp:panel>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onok() {
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error with this ?

Comment: No errors, click event for Button "submit" is not called

Answer (score 0):

Change toolkitscriptmanager instead of script manager. For best reason [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348589/difference-between-script-manager-and-toolkit-script-manager)

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code javascript to call server button click event:

function onOk() {
        __doPostBack("<%= submits.UniqueID %>", "OnClick");

```
}
```